# Custom button/Save URL

Tags: custom-button

I have created a custom create button since we cannot define a lookup value with an action.  I have created the button, but when I go to test it states that the URL no longer exists.
I copied the url from the standard create button:

```
https://cs54.salesforce.com/setup/ui/recordtypeselect.jsp?ent=01I150000017oVu&retURL=%2F0060S000002E9GH&save_new_url=%2Fa03%2Fe%3FCF00N1500000CxfPc%3DAgent%2BTest%2B-%2B2017-03-21%26CF00N1500000CxfPc_lkid%3D0060S000002E9GH%26retURL%3D%252F0060S000002E9G
```

My custom button:

```
/setup/ui/recordtypeselect.jsp?ent=01I150000017oVu
&save_new_url==%2F{Quotes_RFR.Id}
&retURL=%2F{!Opportunity.Id}
&00N1500000HvjMd={!Opportunity.OwnerFullName}
&00N1500000Cxfq6={!Opportunity.Sales_Support_Contact__c}
&00N1500000Cxfsc={!Opportunity.Date_Received__c}
&00N1500000Cxfrg={!Opportunity.Date_Due__c}
&00N1500000CxftK="Being Worked"
```

After I select the record type I get the error:

> Invalid Page Redirection The page you attempted to access has been
>   blocked due to a redirection to an outside website or an improperly
>   coded link or button. Please contact your salesforce.com Administrator
>   for assistance. For more information, see Insufficient Privileges
>   Errors.

Answer (score 1):

In past, had faced similar issues due to encoding of parameters, without which URL becomes invalid as error message suggests.

Should use [URLENCODE](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=custom_links_constructing.htm&type=0) for all the parameters.

Like:

```
{!URLENCODE(Opportunity.OwnerFullName)}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think there is `==` in `save_new_url==%2F{Quotes_RFR.Id}` make it single `=`.

And use [URLENCODE](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=custom_links_constructing.htm&type=0) function for substitution.

```
/setup/ui/recordtypeselect.jsp?ent=01I150000017oVu
&save_new_url=/{!URLENCODE (Quotes_RFR.Id)}
&retURL=/{!URLENCODE (Opportunity.Id)}
&00N1500000HvjMd={!URLENCODE(Opportunity.OwnerFullName)}
```

Comment: I changed it as indicated, but I am getting the error message:Error: Field Quotes_RFR.Id does not exist. Check spelling.

Comment: @Michelle, Probably because you are not using proper field name.

Comment: It is my custom object that I am trying to create off of the opportunity

Answer (score 0):

After much research and trial and error this worked
/setup/ui/recordtypeselect.jsp?ent=01I150000017oVu 
&save_new_url=a03/e 
&retURL={!Opportunity.Id} 
&CF00N1500000HvjMd={!Opportunity.OwnerFullName} 
&CF00N1500000HvjMd_lkid={!User.Full_Name__c} 
&CF00N1500000CxfPc={!Opportunity.Name} 
&CF00N1500000Cxfq6={!Opportunity.Sales_Support_Contact__c} 
&00N1500000Cxfsc={!Opportunity.Date_Received__c} 
&00N1500000Cxfrg={!Opportunity.Date_Due__c}